# How do I enclose all numeric substrings of a string in braces?

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to convert a string so that all numeric subsequences are enclosed in a `{`...`}` pair.

For instance:

```
input_string = "APPL[E]5XXXX"

output_string = "APPL[E]{5}XXXX"
```

Each string may contain one or more digits, for instance `BASIC76XXXXX98ZZZZ` and output should be `BASIC{76}XXXXX{98}zzzz`

Not sure if this possible to achieve. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You should really try something yourself before coming here for help. This isn't a "write my code for me" site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for sure possible.

You want a regex that matches on digits, captures the digits, then substitutes the match with a wrapped set of curly braces.

```
my $input = 'APPL[E]5XXXX';
$input =~ s/(\d+)/{$1}/g;
```

- The `\d+` matches digits.
- The `()` captures and stores in `$1`.
- The `s///` is a substitution regex.
- And finally, the `/g` at the end means 'global', aka, do this for all matches.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$string =~ s/(\d+)/{$1}/g;
```

That will match any consecutive digits and replace them with the first captured substring (`$1` - which coincides with the entire match) surrounded by curly brackets. The `g` is to make sure that all occurrences are replaced.

Comment: @user1844052 if you have parentheses in your regex, and count them from left to right, you can also access what was matched *inside* those subpatterns with `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and so on. Google "regex capturing groups" for more information.

Comment: For a long time is has been bad practice to use `$&` - a capture and `$1` etc. should be used instead. For instance `$string =~ s/(\d+)/{$1}/g`

Comment: @Borodin thanks for letting me know. I'm not really up to speed when it comes to Perl best practices ;).